# PHP use session for radio button or set default

Tags: php, session, if-statement

On my upload form for an image gallery I have two radios - one for "fullsize" and one for "thumbnails". I managed (thx to stackoverflow) to keep the last checked radio button checked, but I'd now also like to set the "full"-one as default, i.e. if there's nothing set (!isset), e.g. when first opening the form, it should be checked. below is how far I got, I really can't see what I'm missing, help please!

```html
<?php
// the session:
session_start();
if(isset($_POST['kategorie'])){
$_SESSION['kategorie']=$_POST['kategorie'];}
if(isset($_POST['size'])){
$_SESSION['size']=$_POST['size'];}
?>

<?php
// and the radio buttons:
<input type="radio" name="size" value="full" id="regularRadio"
        <?php
  if (isset($_SESSION['size'])) {
   if($_SESSION['size'] == "full") {
    echo " checked='checked'"; 
   } elseif (!isset($_SESSION['size'])) {
    echo " checked='checked'";
   }
  }
  ?> >
        <label for="regularRadio">Full size</label>
        <br>         
        <input type="radio" name="size" value="thumb" id="thumbRadio"
        <?php
  if (isset($_SESSION['size'])) {
   if($_SESSION['size'] == "thumb") {
    echo "checked=' checked'"; 
   }
  }
  ?> >
        <label for="thumbRadio">Thumbnail</label>
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use form to do this,otherwise it will not work.When we submit the form,then it will set the value of radio button.
Because HTML forms are used to collect user input and Form elements are different types of input elements, checkboxes, radio buttons, submit buttons, and more.

### So Radio button is the element of form

Comment: thanks for your reply, yes of course it's in a form, i'm just showing the relevant bits of the code here because there's a lot of it ;-) the session stuff works, it's just the bit with elseif(!isset) which doesn't seem to work...